# vsftpd - разграничение прав

Tags: linux, centos, ftp

Здравствуйте! Есть centos 7 с установленным vsftpd и дефолтной директорией /var/ftp. Создал двух виртуальных пользователей user1 и user2. Как дать права первому только на чтение из директории, а второму на чтение/запись?

```html
anonymous_enable=NO
local_enable=YES
write_enable=YES
pam_service_name=vsftpd
#папка по умолчанию
local_root=/var/ftp
anon_upload_enable=YES
anon_mkdir_write_enable=NO
anon_other_write_enable=NO
chroot_local_user=YES
#т.к. будем использовать виртуальных пользователей то нужно привести их к пользователю 
#сервера с минимальными правами
guest_enable=YES
guest_username=ftp
#укажем папку для хранения дополнительных конфигов
user_config_dir=/etc/vsftpd/users/
virtual_use_local_privs=YES
# выставим нужные права
chmod_enable=YES
chown_uploads=YES
chown_username=ftp
# маска создание и чтение файлов - очень важные параметры я убил 2 дня 
# на поиски решения (при #создании каталогов - пользователи не могли в 
# них попасть т.к. не было прав)
local_umask=0022
anon_umask=0007
file_open_mode=0777
listen=YES
listen_port=21
pasv_min_port=30000
pasv_max_port=30999
xferlog_std_format=YES
xferlog_file=/var/log/vsftpd.log
tcp_wrappers=YES
dirmessage_enable=YES
```

```html
# права для user1
local_root=/var/ftp
anon_upload_enable=NO
anon_mkdir_write_enable=NO
anon_other_write_enable=NO
chroot_local_user=NO

# права для user2
local_root=/var/ftp
anon_upload_enable=YES
anon_mkdir_write_enable=YES
anon_other_write_enable=YES
chroot_local_user=NO
```

```html
# ls -lah /var/ftp
total 8.0K
dr-xr-xr-x.  2 ftp  ftp  4.0K May 15 15:11 .
drwxr-xr-x. 21 root root 4.0K May 15 10:17 ..
```